# Problema with python (pip) in ParrotOS

Tags: python, linux, pip, parrot-os

When I try to run programs that require pip on my parrot and it gives me the following error: and i cant understand what happens this and how to solved.

```
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.packaging.utils import canonicalize_name
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
    vendored("requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 627, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1556, in <module>
    class X509StoreFlags(object):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 1577, in X509StoreFlags
    CB_ISSUER_CHECK = _lib.X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK'
```

i try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install pip --upgrade
sudo pip install pyopenssl --upgrade
```

And nothing gives me result

Comment: you first line says `returnn _run_code(code, main_globals, None,`   is this code you wrote? because there's a typo in `returnn`

Comment: it was a copy and paste error,is solved (This is an error, I did not write it.)